# Word-choice when modifying preceding nouns, among past participle, "which", and "as"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, differences, word-usage

Please see the following phrases.

(i) "the language used in"

(ii) "the language which is used in"

(iii) "the language as used in"

(iv) "the language as it is used in"

I understand that a past participle only, the relative pronoun "which", and the conjunction "as" respectively can modify preceding nouns by specifying/limiting (or otherwise) the meaning of them.

However, I am not yet confident about difference of nuance or word-choice.

I can say that (ii) and (iv) styles are preferable when specifying tense is critical in the context, but I'm not sure in other respects regarding word-choice/difference of nuance.

So, could someone explain any difference of nuance and word-choice among them?

Thank you.

Comment: the terms and conditions set forth herein...should mean, the terms and conditions (which are/ have been/ are being) set forth herein... But, the terms and conditions as set forth herein..should mean "the terms and conditions (as they are/ as they have been) set forth herein.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I took that inserted "as" is conjunction. Though it appears to me this type of "as" is not particularly featured in Merriam-Webster, I found in another dictionary a description that "as" can specify/limit the meaning of preceding nouns. Now that I understood the grammar aspect, I'll edit my post so as to focus on  difference of nuance and word-choice. If you have additional comment, it'll be quite appreciated.